# How to send commands and receive responses to OSGi console via a Java Socket?

Tags: java, sockets, osgi

I want to run OSGi framework on another computer (in a main method). So I wanted to know is there any way to connect to the OSGi console from the other computer and manage bundles?

I thought maybe using a `java.net.Socket` would help, and that's how I implemented that. I've used 2 threads. one for processing user input stream, and the other one that processes OSGi Console response. This is the first thread (processes user input stream):

```
    configMap.put("osgi.console", "6666");
    Framework fwk = ff.newFramework(configMap);
    try {
        fwk.start();
    } catch (BundleException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

//__________________________________________________________________//

    try {
        BufferedReader stdIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        Socket socket = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName("0.0.0.0"), 6666);
        printlnInfo("Socket has been created: " + socket.getInetAddress() + ":" + socket.getPort());
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
        ConsoleOutputReciever fr = new ConsoleOutputReciever();
        new Thread(fr).start();
        while (true) {
            String userInput = "";
            while ((userInput = stdIn.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println("--> " + userInput);
                out.write(userInput + "\n");
                out.flush();
            }
            System.out.println("2");
        }
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This is the second thread (processes OSGi Console response):

```
public class ConsoleOutputReciever implements Runnable {

public Scanner in = null;

@Override
public void run() {
    printlnInfo("ConsoleOutputReciever Started");
    try {
        Socket socket = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName("0.0.0.0"), 6666);
        printlnInfo("Socket has been created: " + socket.getInetAddress() + ":" + socket.getPort());
        String osgiResponse = "";
        in = new Scanner(socket.getInputStream());
        try {
            while (true) {
                in = new Scanner(socket.getInputStream());
                while (in.hasNext()) {
                    System.out.println("-- READ LOOP");
                    osgiResponse = in.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("-- " + osgiResponse);
                }
            }
        } catch (IllegalBlockingModeException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

   }
}
```

but I only receive the first response of the OSGi console. like this:

---

--READ LOOP

--

--READ LOOP

ss

--> ss

---

Any ideas about the problem or any other way to connect to OSGi console remotely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using blocking io, thus your inner while loop will *never* finish until the socket is closed.  you need 2 threads to accomplish this with blocking io streams.  1 thread reads from stdin and writes to the socket output stream, the other thread reads from the socket input stream and writes to stdout.

also, you probably want to write a newline after sending the userInput to the osgi console (Scanner.nextLine() eats the newline).

lastly, you don't generally want to use the Print* classes when working with sockets as they hide IOExceptions.

Comment: That's why I've used `socket.setSoTimeout(tms);`. The inner while loop ends (as you can see it prints "1" in output) but I can't understand why the console does not send any responses any more.
Also I have tried multithreading before this and it doesn't make any difference (The outputs are the same). Is there any problems with the way that I send the commands?

Comment: @Hesam - setting a socket timeout is not the solution you are looking for, trust me (read any decent tutorial on blocking io and you will see that you need to handle input/output on separate threads).  please try implementing my suggestions and then see where that gets you.

Comment: @Hesam - yes, you are getting 1, and after that your Scanner is probably useless.  once you get the the "end" of a stream, you won't get any more data from it.

Comment: You are right the Scanner is useless after that. But right now I'm testing the 2 thread solution and it doesn't make any difference. it seem the `nextLine()` is blocking any way.
I've put the inner while in a separate thread.
I'm really confused about this problem. I've tried every thing and nothing seems to work! Any idea about what's wrong?

Comment: I've updated the source code. Would you please give me your comments on the code?

Comment: @Hesam - you're on the right track.  you don't want 2 socket connections, though, you want to share the first one you create with the other thread.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of building your own thing you might want to use one of the remote shells that are available, for example the Apache Felix one at http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-remote-shell.html

Comment: Is there anything similar for equinox?